# Chain multiple dependent queries with RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

so I am trying to 'chain' togther multiple queries that are somewhat dependent on each other, using RTK Query and I'm not getting very far...

APIS

```
import { baseApi } from '@/lib/rtkQuery/baseApi';

export const personContactApi = baseApi
    .enhanceEndpoints({ addTagTypes: ['mail_packs'] })
    .injectEndpoints({
        endpoints: (build) => ({
            createList: build.mutation({
                query: (body) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/person/list/`,
                        method: 'POST',
                        body,
                    };
                },
            }),
            addPersonsToList: build.mutation({
                query: ({ ListId, personArray }) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/person/list/${ListId}/add-persons/`,
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: { persons: personArray },
                    };
                },
            }),
            sendList: build.mutation({
                query: ({ ListId }) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/person/list/${ListId}/submit/`,
                        method: 'POST',
                    };
                },
            }),
        }),
    });

export const { useCreateListMutation, useAddpersonsToListMutation, useSendListMutation } =
    personContactApi;
```

Query functions

```
const [createList, { data: listResponseObject, isSuccess: createListSuccess, isError: createListError }] = useCreateListMutation();

const [addPersonsToListMutation, { isSuccess: addPersonsToListSuccess, isError: addPersonsToListError }] = useAddPersonsToListMutation();

const [sendList, { isSuccess: sendListSuccess, isError: sendListError }] = useSendListMutation();
```

useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        // When list successfully created, add persons to list
        if (createListSuccess) {
            addPersonsToListMutation({
                ListId: listResponseObject?.id,
                personsArray: selectedPersons,
            });
        }
    }, [
        addPersonsToListMutation,
        createListSuccess,
        listResponseObject,
        selectedPersons,
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // When persons have been successfully added to mailing list, send mailing list
        if (addPersonsToListSuccess) {
            sendList({
                listId: listResponseObject?.id,
            });
        }
    }, [
        addPersonsToListSuccess,
        listResponseObject,
        sendList,
    ]);
```

These are the 3 queries / mutations and they need to go in order, once the `create` query is success we fire the `add`, once that is a success we fire the `send`

The `add` and `send` queries are also dependent on an `id` returned in the response from the `createList` query, and the `add` query required an array of ids representing the person objects being added to the list

I've hacked togther a solution using multiple `useEffects` but it is very brittle and obviously not the ideal way to handle this situation, any one have a better way I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this would be to follow one of their official suggestions:

> If you need to access the error or success payload immediately after a mutation, you can chain .unwrap().

In your example, the code would be something like this

```
createList(input_object_goes_here)
  .unwrap()
  .then(createListResponse => {
    addPersonsToListMutation(createListResponse.values_you_need)
      .unwrap()
      .then(addPersonsResponse => sendList({ listId: addPersonsResponse.id }))
  })
```

Hope I got the syntax right, but you should get the idea.

Source: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling